# Roots of Complex Numbers As Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, radicals

I have a question about the roots of complex numbers, ie., $\sqrt{z}$, $\sqrt[3]{z}$, etc.
Obviously, these can be calculated using DeMoivre's Formula for complex exponentials, but is there any way to incorporate them as an analytic function, as has been done with $log(z)$ and $Log(z)$? I'm somewhat experienced in Complex Analysis (meaning I took a first course which went up to isolated singularities and the Residue Theorem) but I've never seen anything pertaining to this

Any ideas?

Comment: $\exp ( \frac12 \log z )$, $\exp ( \frac13 \log z)$, etc.

Comment: Here we go$$z^\alpha = e^{\alpha\log z}.$$

Comment: Generally you rewrite $z^{1/n} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\log (z)}$.  If you mean the `log(z)` vs `Log(z)` thing as choosing a branch cut, then yes you have to do that here (I'm no expert, but I recall hearing something like the Riemannian surface associated to $z^{1/n}$ "repeats" itself after $n$-sheets, whereas the $\log$ Riemannian surface never does).

Comment: This is also related to the topological properties of the plane and the Riemann mapping theorem. From big Rudin: http://i.imgur.com/HsXce7U.png

Comment: Well I haven't gotten to Riemann Surfaces or the Riemann Mapping Thereom yet. I'll have to look into that soon.